# Duplicate fragment allocation when using ViewPager with different layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, heap-dump

I've observed very strange Android fragment allocation behaviour in my application recenty.

My application has two fragments and two layouts:

- portrait layout with ViewPager as root view;
- landscape layout without Viewpager (in this example LinearLayout is used as root view).

The reason for this setup - I can display all fragments simultaneously while in landscape mode.

And this works fine until we don't look inside heap more closely. I've looked and I saw that when:

- I start application in portrait mode with ViewPager;
- change orientation to landscape, expecting that **two** new fragments will be created;
- **four** fragments are created, all in RESUMED state.

So I've played with it for a while, tried different setups, google it etc and find no answer. Finally, I've create demo application by Android Studio wizard (ViewPager with tabs), remove some boilerplate, add landscape layout to "layout-land" folder and push it to [GitHub](https://github.com/dddpaul/android-ViewPagerBug).

I do not quote sources here for the brevity sake, hope it's okay.

My questions are:

1. Is this pattern I've selected is inappropriate? Maybe it's better to use ViewPager in both layouts but show 2 pages simultaneously in landscape mode like [here](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/08/20/multiple-view-viewpager-options.html)? Or totally get rid of ViewPager and use more classic Lars Vogel's multi-pane pattern?
2. Can it be a bug in Android runtime?
3. And if it's a proper pattern and not an Android runtime bug, why these dublicate fragments are being allocated, for Christ's sake?